How to create an application layout with React MUI?
I want to create an application layout for my app relying on React MUI. The layout should be

Toolbar
Page content ( stretched across page )
Footer ( at bottom, pushed by page content )

which looks like

I started with ( sandbox: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xg78wu?file=Demo.tsx )
import * as React from 'react';
import AppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';

export default function Demo() {
  return (
    <>
      <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
        <AppBar position="static">
          <Toolbar>Logo</Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
        <Container sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>Page content goes here</Container>
        <Container>The footer at the bottom</Container>
      </Box>
    </>
  );
}

Unfortunately the main content is not stretching across the page. I also tried to use a grid ( https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xg78wu-sixzuf?file=Demo.tsx )
import * as React from 'react';
import AppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid2';

export default function Demo() {
  return (
    <Grid container direction="column">
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>Logo</Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Container sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>Page content goes here</Container>
      <Container>The footer at the bottom</Container>
    </Grid>
  );
}

but that didn't help. What is wrong or missing?

Set the height of your wrapper element to be the full height of the viewport 100vh, and ensure that you don't have any margin or padding on the body/html elements
// Note: you should set the margin on the `body` element to be 0
export default function Demo() {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', height: '100vh' }}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>Logo</Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Container sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>Page content goes here</Container>
      <Container>The footer at the bottom</Container>
    </Box>
  );
}


The issue occurs because the AppBar component from Material-UI typically has a fixed position by default, causing the content underneath to appear hidden. To resolve this, you can add some top padding or margin to your main content container (or to the parent .checking01 div) to account for the height of the AppBar.
HTML
<div className="completePage">
     <AppBar className="appBar">
     <Toolbar>Logo</Toolbar>
     </AppBar>
     <Container className="content">Page content goes here</Container>
     <Container className="footer">The footer at the bottom</Container>
</div>

css
.completePage {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding-top: 64px;
}

.appBar {
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
}

.footer {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}


thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I'm looking for a builtin solution :( Vue/Vuetify has it...  https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/application-layout/#application-layout
